# Generating sub-domains

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, subdomain

I need to create sub-domains for users as they create accounts. I don't really know if I can or not, but I'd like to just use fake sub-domains. With ASP.net Core, can I use routing to accept a request to http://username.mysite.com, without a real sub domain existing? Or am I going to have to create a sub-domain at my domain provider for each user?

With ASP.net Core, how do I handle sub-domains when a request comes in? Is it the same as MVC5 in the sense that an Http Module exists or a custom route is needed?

Comment: You always need a record in the DNS for any hostname you use and depends on the hosting configuration if you need anything else set up. Wildcard hostnames might be possible.

Comment: Can someone comment on why i was downvoted? You should leave a remark as to why so the OP can make improvements, corrections or close if needed.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question is pretty broad and doesn't include any code. It'd be easier to answer if you had a concrete sample that wasn't currently working.

Comment: The question was how to do it in the first place, so i wouldn't have any code ;) I don't know how I'm supposed to support sub-domains. I will try to be a bit more clear on what specifically I'm trying to achieve though